# Converting Byte array (Byte[]) to a video (Android)

Tags: android, android-videoview

So i have uploaded my video to my amazon DataBase, and now i Want to download it and display it, here is the part of my code where i download it:

```
S3ObjectInputStream content = s3.getObject(
                            Constants.getVideoBucket(),
                            keyList.get(i).getKey().toString())
                            .getObjectContent();
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);
```

Now I have the byte array that has the video, but i dont know what to do next. What should i do? I want to display it on a VideoView that I have ready.

help will be much apreciated

ps: i dont want to write down the video to the sd card! (imagine a youtube video, it gisplays but it wont write to ur sd card every video you watch.!)!!!!!!!!!!!!

EDIT1: i did this with the pictures:

```
S3ObjectInputStream content = s3.getObject(
                            Constants.getPictureBucket(),
                            keyList.get(i).getKey().toString())
                            .getObjectContent();
                    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmaparray.get(i), 0,
                            bitmaparray.get(i).length);             
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

as you can see, i converted the byte array to bitmap and then displayed it to a imageview, could you please help me to do the same with the video one???

Comment: What format is the video data in?

Comment: i really dont know haha how can i find the format?? i jsut savbed a video done with a samsung galaxy

Comment: @fadden I also have the same problem in a different context. Can the problem be solved with specific format? In that case, I can consider converting the videos. Currently, I have video in flv,mp4 and webm formats.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to decode the byte array(.h264 format) in to video in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123759/how-to-decode-the-byte-array-h264-format-in-to-video-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with appropriate permissions.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("sdcard path where you want to save video");
out.write(bytes);
out.close();
videoView.setVideoPath(“path to saved video“).
```

Comment: and then??? i also saw this answer in another post, but i dont know how to manage the video

Comment: then you can access the saved video.whether you want to play it or do something else

Comment: but is it posible to play it without saving it? imagine youtube, if you save everyvideo you see you'll have ur card full in a day.

Comment: No my answer is about the saving of the video.

Comment: Well i didnt asked for that, so ur answer is useles.

Comment: i also still didn't found answer for this. if someone found please tell me